# How do Pitiless Plunderer and Bontu's Last Reckoning interact with each other?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Would [Pitiless Plunderer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPitiless%20Plunderer%5d) create treasure tokens if you had two other different creatures on the battlefield when a board wipe like [Bontu's Last Reckoning](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBontu%27s%5d%2b%5bLast%5d%2b%5bReckoning%5d) is cast?

Answer (score -3):

Yes.

Triggered abilities trigger once per event, and the trigger conditions defines the event.

"Whenever a creature dies" will trigger every time a creature dies.

Since Pitiless Plunderer is phrased similarly to this, it triggers twice.

"Whenever one or more creatures die" will trigger every time one or more creatures die simultaneously.

Since Pitiless Plunderer isn't phrased similarly to this, it doesn't trigger only once.

Comment: Where did *"Whenever creatures die"* come from?  Neither of the cards in the question says that - are you referring to some other card that uses this text?

Comment: @BJ Myers, It's an example of what wouldn't trigger for each death. Since the ability in question isn't phrased that way, it doesn't behave that way.

Comment: There are no cards that say "Whenever creatures die" or "Whenever one or more creatures die" or anything like that, so I think it's not really helpful to refer to that wording.

Comment: @murgatroid99, Quite the opposite many triggers trigger only once even if multiple X happens simultaneously. Are you suggesting I change the question because they used a bad example?

Comment: What do you mean "they used a bad example"? You introduced the phrase "Whenever creatures die" to this question, and no card has ever been printed with that trigger condition.

Comment: `many triggers trigger only once even if multiple X happens simultaneously` - I've never seen one that works this way.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: @BJ Myers, e.g. Damage. Some trigger on damage from a source, some trigger on damage.

Comment: @murgatroid99, You answered your own question. It's bad example because no card has it. /// Why do you keep saying I introduced the possibility of the trigger only triggering once; the OP did. That's their question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the OP is asking "do you get treasure tokens, or not?", i.e. the standard "do I get death triggers when multiple creatures die including the one with the triggered ability". I don't think they're asking whether you get one treasure token or two.

Comment: @murgatroid99, Then why did they specifically mention they have two other creatures on the battlefield, and if they get treasures (plural)? Compare "Why is there a blue elephant in the room?" vs "Why is there an elephant in the room?" Unlike the person asking the second question, the person asking the first question is not surprised that there is an elephant in the room; they are surprised by its colour.

Comment: @BJ Myers, "Whenever ~ becomes blocked" vs "whenever ~ is blocked by a creature"

Comment: @BJ Myers, "Whenever ~ deals damage" vs "whenever ~ deals damage to a player"